# Array Output comes in @{Name=1234} but i only need 1234 in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
$date = get-date -format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$save = Get-ChildItem \\ABC\xyz\wbc | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date+' 2:30 AM' -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date+' 5:35 AM'} | Select Name
for($i=1;$i -eq 62;$i++)
{
Select-String -Path "\\ABC\xyz\wbc\"+$save[$i]+"\"+$save[$i]+"_2"+"\.out" -Pattern "End save of data." 
}
```

Above is the code that I have written till now.
I have to read multiple files under a directory for a pattern of word, some part of the directory is static i.e.   \ABC\xyz\wbc after this portion of the path there are folders created serially I just want to capture these directories one by one which are within specific date and time range and inserts it into the path like  "\ABC\xyz\wbc\"+$save[0]. If I try $save[0] I am getting output in the format like

```
Name
---- 
16471
```

I am expecting the path to be like \ABC\xyz\wbc\16471\16471_2*.out so that I can use it in select-string

Comment: $arr = @{Name=1234}; $arr.Values will get 1234. Use $arr | Get-Member see orther detial.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Select -ExpandProperty Name` instead of `Select Name`

for the array you may try:

```
foreach($element in $save) {
    '\\ABC\xyz\wbc\{0}\{0}_2.out' -f $element 
}
```

what should return

```
\ABC\xyz\wbc\16471\16471_2*.out
```

Comment: hey Guenther, that did work as I get output now in format of 1234 only but how do I pull out elements from array and add it in the static portion of the path

Comment: i updated my answer. not sure this answers your question. if not please try to ask another question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in parenthesis and adding .name at the end

$save = (Get-ChildItem \ABC\xyz\wbc | Where-Object { $*.LastWriteTime -gt $date+' 2:30 AM' -and $*.LastWriteTime -lt $date+' 5:35 AM'}).name